# Explicit formula for nth derivative of $(2x^2+a)^b$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I'm attempting to find an explicit formula for $\frac{d^n}{dx^n} \left[ \left(2x^2+a \right) ^b \right]$ where $a$ and $b$ are constants, $b$ and $n$ are integers, and $n>b$.

Wolfram tells me that the first few are:[image]

I am having trouble seeing any sort of pattern so I am wondering if anyone knows of an explicit formula or knows how one would obtain an explicit formula.

Comment: How $b$ is an integer you could use the binomial theorem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $b>0:$

Using $ \left(2x^2+a \right) ^b =\sum_{j=0}^b {b \choose j}2^ja^{b-j}x^{2j}$ we have

$\frac{d^n}{dx^n} \left[ \left(2x^2+a \right) ^b \right]=\sum_{\frac n2\leq j\leq b} {b \choose j}2^ja^{b-j}\frac{(2j)!}{(2j-n)!}x^{2j-n}$